# Aliasing / Shortening the Namespaces in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

There are two namespaces with class Image. One is `iTextSharp` and another WPF `System.Windows.Control.Image`.

Now I've to use complete reference i.e. `System.Windows.Control.Image a = new ..` and `iTextSharp.text.Image b = new ...`

Is there any way to Aliasing the namespace, so I don't have to write complete namespace.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yeps, just use:

```
using Img = System.Windows.Control.Image;
```

In your namespace declaration.

Then you can use the `Img` aliased name as you used the fully qualified name previously.

Comment: I often do this when I have similar class names for dev and test code.  `Dev.ParkingServer`, `Test.ParkingServer`.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
using yourAlias = System.Windows.Control.Image;
```